# "TypeError: can't convert String into Integer" when trying to CTRL+click or SHIFT+click in watir-webdriver/selenium-webdriver script

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, modifiers

I am trying to select multiple items in a date picker defined as table, in a cucumber script  using watir-webdriver/selenium-webdriver on Chrome browser.

The date picker allows Ctrl and Shift as modifiers.

This is the code for a cell:

```
<div type="button" class="datepicker_day" onclick="if(!ample.$instance(this).$isAccessible()) return; DatePicker.onSelectDay(ample.$instance(this), '2011/06/03')" onmouseover="if(!ample.$instance(this).$isAccessible()) return;if (!this.className.match(/_day-disabled/)) this.className += 'datepicker_day-hover'" onmouseout="if(!ample.$instance(this).$isAccessible()) return; if (!this.className.match(/_day-disabled/)) this.className = this.className.replace('datepicker_day-hover', '')">3</div>
```

And this is a sample to what the datepicker is behaving -

http://demo.essentialobjects.com/Demos/Calendar/Designs/Windows%20(Multi-Month)/Demo.aspx

I have tried to use:

```
driver.action.key_down(:shift).
click(element).
click(second_element).
perform
```

but I get "TypeError: can't convert String into Integer".

```
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:59:in `[]'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:59:in `add_backtrace'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:23:in `error'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:50:in `assert_ok'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:54:in `new'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:54:in `create_response'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:64:in `request'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:35:in `call'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:430:in `raw_execute'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:408:in `execute'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:274:in `sendModifierKeyToActiveElement'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keyboard.rb:26:in `press'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:122:in `block in perform'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:121:in `each'
from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:121:in `perform'
```

Was anyone able to use this in his code?
Or has anyone a solution for sending modifiers to mouse events? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide sample HTML or perhaps refer us to a demo site with the control you are using?   it would help to reproduce the problem and/or perhaps come up with a solution

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with sample code for a cell.

Comment: I have deleted watir-webdriver tag because you are not using it. You are using selenium-webdriver. Is there a reason why you have added watir-webdriver tag back?

Comment: I added the watir-webdriver tag because maybe some watir-webdriver users had this issue and solved it in other ways. But if it bothers you, Ok, let's keet it as you like. The idea is that I am willing to use any solution whether I use selenium-webdriver or watir-webdriver as long as I can go on with my work :) I hope you understand my reasons to add the tag :)

Comment: You should make it explicit then that you are open to a solution in another tool. I did not get that from your question. HTML you have provided is not enough. It would be the best if you could provide link to the page. If that is not possible, then provide minimal HTML that still reproduces date picker functionality.

Comment: Added a link to something that is similar to what I am testing.

Comment: Now you are talking. :) See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to Watir-Webdriver I asked Jari (the main driving force behind Watir-webdriver) about this and got the following answer, which may give you a path to pursue if you need this badly enough

> There's nothing exposed in watir-webdriver (yet), but you should be
>   able to do it with the actions API in WebDriver (see
>   http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/2.10.0/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder).
>   I'm not sure how well-supported this is across browsers - but from the
>   Java tests (which are the most extensive) it looks like it's currently
>   only supported on Firefox + Linux:
>
> http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/CombinedInputActionsTest.java#50

I also created a [feature-request](https://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/issues/105) in the Watir-Webdriver project on Github, if this is something you need, you may want to comment on it to make your needs known.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am running my tests on Win machines. I think that you wrote everything that I needed in the Watir-Webdriver request :) .

Comment: watir-webdriver works on windows systems.. the limitation is likely the 'actions API' in webdriver.    Watir uses some different methods to do things, but I don't know if this is possible there either.. I'm making a few enquiries about it on the google watir general group.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

This will select December 1-6 2009 from the third calendar on the page:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/"
browser.p(:id => "date3").span(:text => "1").click
browser.p(:id => "date3").span(:text => "6").click
```

I did not notice that calendar responds to shift or ctrl (manually). The first click will select start date, the second one end date.

Comment: Thank you Željko for the efforts, and I'm sorry for wasting you time. I wasn't paying attention to that grid and yes, you are right it doesn't respond to modifiers. But it's not the answer to my solution. I will dig more into finding a date picker with the same properties as the one I want to interact with.

Comment: Or you could save the page to disk and removed everything but the date picker (and required javascript) and post it somewhere (dropbox, github...).

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice that calendar responds to shift or ctrl (manually). You can select up to 5 days by clicking the day. If you select sixth, the first one that you have selected will automatically be unselected.

This will select November 1 and 3 2011:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://nogray.com/calendar.php#tryit"
browser.span(:id => /ng_button_.*_icon/, :index => 1).click # open calendar
browser.td(:id => /11_1_2011/).click
browser.td(:id => /11_3_2011/).click
```

Comment: I appreciate the efforts, but still doesn't solve my problem. In my code, when clicking the second date, the first one is de-selected

Comment: Well, you either have to provide the link to _your_ application, or provide the page for download.

Comment: This is one datepicker allowing shift: http://demo.essentialobjects.com/Demos/Calendar/Designs/Windows%20(Multi-Month)/Demo.aspx

Comment: Yeah the new updated site at essentialobjects does demonstrate the behavior your indicated.   I'm stuck however in terms of how we can manage a shift-click operation.

Comment: I am struggling with this for a while now, but I ran out of ideas.